# Bootstrap datepicker not showing in fancybox

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, fancybox

I am using fancybox to get a form with ajax. In this form i have a field that should be a bootstrap datepicker. My script works- i dont get any errors and when i click on the field i can see in the developer tools that the datepicker`<div>` is being appended before the closing body tag. However this div is not visible anywhere. I gave it `z-index:9999999 !important` and still nothing. I should mention that the script that activates the datepicker is appended is in the html that the ajax call from fancybox returns, but I dont think this is a problem since the datepicker div is appended correctly to the html.

Comment: Are you calling .datepicker() on the div after it is appended? Note: if you call it right after an async ajax call, it will be called before the div is appended.

Comment: Have you checked it's position and visibility? If you are using Chrome Developer Tools, then select de `<div>` in the "Elements" pane and in the Console type: `$0.offsetParent`. If the result is `null`, then the element is not visible. If it is visible, then check the values for `$0.offsetLeft` and `$0.offsetTop`. With that info I could probably make some conjetures